# disk cannot be formated

Tags: hard-drive, format

I have problem with my external 500GB disk. I connected it to computer, i cant see it at My computer, but i see it at disk managment, or in devices and printers. Disk managment show disk format: RAW. I have saved all data from it. I tried to format it, but it shown a error:"disk cannot be formated" I tried to delete Volume, create new Volume, change driver letter... Nothings helped. I looked at lot of forums and topic, and nothing helped me. I used TestDisk, no error. Disk is not making any strange noise.

Can i save the Disk? Thanks for help.

Comment: Maybe the disk is already formatted. Have you tried to just assign a letter to the drive? Show us a printscreen with the opened Context Menu on it. On which Windows version are you?

Comment: can you tell us which model is it?

Comment: Try the steps in my answer to http://superuser.com/questions/509992/unable-to-format-disk-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/756613#756613

Comment: Look for the manufacturer tool that offers secure erase or also called zero fill/write zeros. You can also use any other software for secure erasing a drive. You need to make a single zero fill of the drive, this will erase all the data on the HDD including any partition information and MBR. Once done you should be able to initialize the disk from Disk Management and them partition and format it.

Comment: i have letter assigned. i used win 7 and 10.

Comment: tony: i tryed this. when  i perform  clear i get a error

Answer (score 0):

Before you can format a raw hard drive you must create a partition on it first.

Go to Control Panel>System & Security>Admin Tools>Create and Format Hard Disk Partitions.

Select the raw drive/partition then right-click and choose Delete Volume.

Right-click it again and create a new partition, allocate a drive letter and choose the Quick Format option.

You can do it with [easeus partition master](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm).

Comment: I'm guessing based on your account history that your recommendation is genuine, but this post was flagged as spam because we've had a lot of spam in the past from the creators of the partition software you linked to. I've cleared the spam flag, and it's up to you what to do with the post, just wanted to explain.

Comment: I have partition created. I deleted old, and created new, and after i create new, it write formating... and later, it write a error: Format cannot be performed.