# Can't find the file specified

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, dd

So I inturrupted a dd for windows operation, and now my usb stick won't work. I saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/509992/unable-to-format-disk-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified) post but, it's solution doesn't work for me, as i don't have a chromebook. Attempts to format the drive just say "The system cannot find the file specified." as seen here:

[image]

Comment: use diskpart to clean the uSB drive: http://www.howtogeek.com/235824/how-to-clean-a-flash-drive-sd-card-or-internal-drive-to-fix-partition-and-capacity-problems/ **ATTENTION** make sure that you selected the correct drive and not different ones otherwise you have data loos.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Make that an answer and i'll mark it as **the** answer. you got 5 minutes before i do it myself lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Windows disk management MMC snapin fails, you can use the [command line tool diskpart](http://www.howtogeek.com/235824/how-to-clean-a-flash-drive-sd-card-or-internal-drive-to-fix-partition-and-capacity-problems/)

- Open [cmd.exe as admin](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2790-elevated-command-prompt-open-windows-10-a.html) and run `diskpart`

[image]

- run `list disk` to list all available disks and use `select disk NUMBER` to select the USB flash drive

[image]

and now run `clean` to clean the drive.

[image]

Now run Disk Management, create a new Volume on the flash drive.

Comment: I said 10 minutes but then i fell asleep. Thanks for your answer, you saved my ass.

Answer (score 0):

If above not work - like in my case, you can have wrong or badly builded partition format:
[image: different partition format:]

Try to convert MBR partition to GPT. I've done it in MiniTool Partition Wizard app.

You can easly convert it right clicking and choosing coresponding option:
[image: converting drive format]

After that it should work even without formating (I could access files prevously saved on that drive)

Answer (score -1):

Cleaning in DISKPART does not always work (it didn't for me).  See [Recovering a Partially Formatted USB Thumb Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/338059/recovering-a-partially-formatted-usb-thumb-drive/1657585#1657585) for some good answers for USB sticks that are proving difficult to recover.

Comment: "See there" is a comment, not a good answer.

Comment: OK, but the best answer there is really long (and not mine) and it didn't seem a good idea to copy it all over.  I have been looking at several SuperUser posts on this problem, and that post seems to have the best answers.  Surely it is helpful to point people to where the answer is.  I did an answer here not a comment because comments don't always get read (or even displayed by default).