# Rufus damaged my usb and windows can't detect it

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive, bootable-media

So, I've been using rufus for a long time and never have I ever experienced something like this. Today, I was creating bootable usb with rufus and all of a sudden everything stopped and I got an error which I don't remember what excatly it said. Now, my usb is not detected by windows. If I try to start windows with my usb plugged into my pc - it won't boot, pc will freeze on bios thingy until I unplugg usb from pc and when I plug it back in when windows loads, it will read usb for a few seconds and then it will disappear again (and even if I try to click on it while is still visable, everything will just freeze). I can only see my usb in disk managmanet, but sadly there's no options available there - everything is grayed out. Another weird thing is when I unplugged wifi usb adapter from my pc and then tried to put it back in when the usb was still plugged into my pc, wifi usb adapter didn't work until I unplugged usb from pc. The saddest thing about this, it's not even my usb. So please, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: when windows detects your USB, check whether rufus can read it.If it can burn again. Or using poweriso you can clean the USB if there's anything wrong with sector data.

Comment: use diskpart to clean the USB thumb drive: http://superuser.com/a/1091111/174557