# DiskPart has encountered an error: The system cannot find the file specified. See the System Event Log for more information

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb, diskpart

I was using Linux to create a bootable Linux installation media when after a few times going back and forth with unsuccessful attempts with DD and Disks restoring image and then ISO image writer and many bootable media creators, the 32GB SanDisk USB ultra fit drive stopped working, any attempt to recover it failed. I tried anything said here 
[Recovering a Partially Formatted USB Thumb Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/338059/recovering-a-partially-formatted-usb-thumb-drive)
and here
[Unable to format disk: 'The system cannot find the file specified'](https://superuser.com/questions/509992/unable-to-format-disk-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)
with no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

USB drives tend to die most commonly whilst being wiped clean and re-written, especially when boot sectors are involved. Check warranty status on the drive and see if you can return it, then buy another.

Comment: Thanks a lot for stopping by. This happened a few times before but I was able to recover the USB drive. I guess this is something to do with File Allocation Tables and its addressing in the media and incompatibilities between Linux and Windows and even maybe other software. However I think this should be recoverable and easier than going through Warranty status.