# unable to change driver letter/format /view files on USB drive previously used as a flash space for linux centos 7

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, centos

The device of discussion is: Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 USB Device
Performing below actions on Operating system: windows 10

I used this 64GB as a flash space for the iso file for centos 7 ( linux) which I successfully installed on another computer.

I want to format the Kingston so I can continue to use it as means of portable storage for files, as I did before. 
There are a couple of problems: 
 
1) the device is recognized as a disk driver but I cannot see it in Devices directory of windows 
[image]
[image]

2) When formatting it and assigning a new letter it does not complete the operation successfully. And gives this error
[image]
[image]

In Device Manager:
 - I have tried "Update Driver" latest driver is on it. I bought it a couple days ago. 
 - I also tried "uninstall device" , restarted the computer , and the device is recognized and shows up once re-connected
 - I have disabled quick start, and the "uninstall device" method together, but that only launches the iso file for linux on the kingston
 - I have also tried the format / assign new letter method which gives the error above.

I am out of avenues to try for this.

Comment: Did you try solutions (`DISKPART` etc) in this question? [Unable to format disk: 'The system cannot find the file specified'](https://superuser.com/questions/509992/unable-to-format-disk-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Answer (score 0):

When you install any kind of linux distributions on a usb drive, it converts file system to ext4 or ext3, file systems used by linux.
To solve this problem, install PowerISO, go to tools, select clean usb, select your drive, click on clean.

Now, without removing the USB, format it using windows format tool(right click on pendrive---> format), select FAT32 or NTFS.

It should work fine now.