# USB flash drive not formatting

Tags: partitioning, liveusb, disk-utility

I'm currently trying to format a usb drive to be used as a Win10 home boot drive.
It has previously been a Fedora workstation and Fedora Server boot drive.
I used the DISKPART utility in the windows 10 shell to wipe the drive, which had had a efi partition on it. 
Now, whenever I try to format it, it fails and says "The volume was created successfully but not formatted" and "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Did you use the diskpart `CLEAN` command?

Comment: yes, it was the disk #2 and I selected it and used `CLEAN` on it @HackSlash

Comment: Are you using `Disk Management` to create partitions before formatting? (You can't format a drive with no partitions)

Comment: I am using Disk Management  and doing `Create New Simple Volume` and the error messages show up after I run through the wizard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to format disk: 'The system cannot find the file specified'](https://superuser.com/questions/509992/unable-to-format-disk-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this from an elevated command prompt:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk X
clean
create partition primary
active
format fs=Fat32 quick
```

If Windows can't recover the drive then you will need to boot to Linux and format it in a way that is visible from both Linux and Windows. Like FAT32 or exFAT depending on the size of the drive.

Comment: upon selecting the disk and running `clean`, I was given the error message `DiskPart has encountered an error: Access is denied`\
I am running this as an administrator

Comment: Run Windows update. Check for chipset and usb driver updates. Reboot. Try it again.

Comment: also, I am running a Win10 home insider preview version 21337.rs_prerelease.210312-1502 if that makes any significant differences