# How to reformat a thumb drive that is listed as having 0bytes free?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, partition-recovery, diskpart

I have a thumb drive that has somehow been corrupted. When I plugged it in, Windows prompted me to reformat, so I did, and that did nothing. I checked on the drive in computer management and there was my 3.75gb of data, unallocated. No clue how that happened.

But, I did some googling and found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/338059/recovering-a-partially-formatted-usb-thumb-drive) useful guide to reformatting. I thought my problems were solved. However, in diskpart, the drive is listed has having 0b available. So, when I tried to run `create partition primary`, Windows complained that it couldn't make a partition with the amount of space available. Keep in mind that in computer management, I can still see the 3.75gb unallocated space, so that utility is telling me one thing, and diskpart is saying another.
[This is the exact message diskpart gave me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6QRK.png). Also, if I try to reformat via computer management, I get a "Server threw an exception" error.

What can I do to save this thumb drive?

EDIT

So it turns out I didn't dig hard enough / Google dropped the ball. Currently reading [this](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem) answer. If it doesn't help, I will update accordingly.

Comment: Why bother wasting your time? t's a 4GB drive... throw it away and buy a new one, a 4GB thumb drive can be easily purchased for under $5.

Comment: @acejavelin That's what I ended up doing, I just ordered a 32GB one for 10 bucks. The original cost me 20 about 7 years ago, so that was a bit mind boggling for me.

Comment: Run cmd
Format \? Maybe you can do a lower level format. thats weird that you can't get it back working. Partition table got messed up? You can always save it and have Windows turn it into an install disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [USB flash drive not working or is appearing as an empty disk drive, Disk Management reports "No Media" with 0 bytes size](https://superuser.com/questions/871850/usb-flash-drive-not-working-or-is-appearing-as-an-empty-disk-drive-disk-managem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in the linked questions, little can be done when a flashdrive is listed as 0b. I decided to simply purchase a new flash drive instead of delving any deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/). Choose your USB drive under `Device`, choose the desired partition scheme and file system, provide a volume label, uncheck `Create a bootable disk using` and hit `Start`.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to come across this when i was having trouble with sandisk that i wanted to format
via disk management windows 10 from USB 3.0 port. I deleted volume and then went to create new 1 nut it threw acceptation error. Ended up trying in the other 2.0 USB port and it worked this time.
So try different port maybe.