# Unable to access and format a USB drive, which is seen in Disk Management but not This PC on Window 10

Tags: windows-10, command-line, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I have tried steps on two posts in this superuser thread: [Recovering a Partially Formatted USB Thumb Drive](https://superuser.com/questions/338059/recovering-a-partially-formatted-usb-thumb-drive/1657585#1657585)

These are my attempts:

**Attempt 1:** referring to user LJD200's post

I ran these commands on CMD as administrator:

```
list disk
select disk
clean
```

The 'clean' command resulted in this error:

```
DiskPart has encountered an error: Access is denied.
See the System Event Log for more information.
```

I then continued to run these commands:

```
convert mbr
create partition primary
format fs=fat32 QUICK
```

Again, I saw this error:

```
DiskPart has encountered an error: The system cannot find the file specified.
See the System Event Log for more information.
```

**Attempt 2:** referring to user Mark Tomlin's long post

These are the commands I ran:

```
list disk
select disk X
detail disk
```

And cmd showed detail of the usb drive:

```
Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 USB Device
Disk ID: XXXXXXXX
Type: USB
Status:Online
Path: 0
Target: 0
LUN ID: 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No 
Crashdump Disk : No
Clustered Disk : No
```

I then continued running these commands:

```
select volume X
FORMAT RECOMMENDED OVERRIDE
```

which yielded `DiskPart has encountered an error: The system cannot find the file specified. See the System Event Log for more information.`

Then I continued with this command:`FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL='xx' QUICK COMPRESS`
and the same error appeared.

I then ran:`select disk x` and `clean all` and the error was:
`DiskPart has encountered an error: Access is denied. See the System Event Log for more information.`

After that, I ran `list partition` and cmd showed `There are no partitions on this disk to show`

I followed Mark's steps to run these commands:

```
ONLINE DISK
ATTRIBUTES DISK CLEAR READONLY
CLEAN
```

where the last command returned the same error as `clean all`

Finallly, I ran `convert mbr` and `create partition primary`.

At this point, the status of the usb drive on Disk Management showed that it was "RAW, Healthy(Active, primary partition).

Any advise from here is greatly appreciated as I've been stuck at this for quite some time. Thanks!

Comment: Error message says: `See the System Event Log for more information.`. Have you looked at it?

Answer (score 0):

Windows seems to be having a hard time keeping it recognized or "active" (not the right word but i digress) due to some partitioning error.

i personally had an SD card that was doing a similar if not identical problem to this, and Windows would not format and partition it -- however, using USB passthrough to a Ubuntu guest virtual machine (i used VirtualBox but i assume any will work), i was able to format it perfectly fine.

you could also probably do so with a Ubuntu live disk USB if you so chose to, but that involves completely shutting down your system to boot to it and that's just a hassle if you ask me.

if none of the above works, it could be your drive is either corrupt beyond repair -- in which case, i'm sorry for your loss, but dead USBs and SD cards are essentially useless.